# jQuery removeClass addClass animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, addclass, removeclass

Trying to do a very very simple jQuery animation...
The nav element will animate with negative margin but the class .nav_btn2 is not applied so the nav element will not animate back to the original margin. Been at this for hours, all night actually... 7:47am in the morning and I haven't slept, blah.

jQuery v1.7.1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.nav_btn').on('click',function() {
            $('nav').animate({marginLeft: '-445'}, 500);
            $('.nav_btn').removeClass('nav_btn').addClass('nav_btn2');
        });

        $('.nav_btn2').on('click',function() {
            $('nav').animate({marginLeft: '445'}, 500);
            $('.nav_btn2').removeClass('nav_btn2').addClass('nav_btn');
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<nav>
   <img src="" alt="Detour Bar" id="logo" />

   <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav_btn">BLOG</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav_btn">PHOTOS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav_btn">CALANDER</a></li>
      <li><a href="info.php" class="nav_btn">INFO</a></li>
   </ul>

   <div id="menu_btn" class="nav_btn">
   </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
      height: 100%;
      width: 425px;
      padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
      background: rgb(255,255,255);
      background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
      border-right: 7px solid #000;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
}

nav ul {
      padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
      list-style: none;
}

nav li {
      padding: 0px 55px 0px 0px;
      text-align: right;
}

nav a {
      font-size: 4em;
      color: #000;
}

#menu_btn {
      width: 40px;
      height: 161px;
      border: 10px solid #000;
      border-top: 15px solid #000;
      border-bottom: 20px solid #000;
      border-top-right-radius: 10px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
      background: rgb(0,0,0);
      background-image: url(img/menu.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      position: absolute;
      top: 40px;
      right: -60px;
}
```

Jquery v1.7.1 working... Thanks to @micha

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click','.nav_btn',function() {
        $('nav').animate({marginLeft: '-445'}, 500);
        $('.nav_btn').removeClass('nav_btn').addClass('nav_btn2');
        });

        $(document).on('click','.nav_btn2',function() {
        $('nav').animate({marginLeft: '0'}, 500);
        $('.nav_btn2').removeClass('nav_btn2').addClass('nav_btn');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Post the HTML that accompanies this code, please.

Comment: I created [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmrMW/) using the Javascript, HTML and CSS you posted. Seems like it moves the navigation off the screen (which is what I'd expect), and modifies the classes on the links (I inspected with Firebug), but... what next? There's nothing to click on (because the links are off the edge of the screen) to get it back.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, There is one div id="#menu_btn" that acts like a tab that sticks out from the edge of the screen, it also has a class of .nav_btn.
PS. Thanks for all the help so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the on function in the wrong way. You want the on function be like the old live function and not like the old bind function.

So you need to do it like this: `$(document).on("click", selector, function() { ... });`
Because the document will always exists and the document will always check if your selector is in the document when you click on it.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jmrMW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor the code, it is not a good way I think, I have change @Anthony Grist code so that you can do it work with a little tweak:

http://jsfiddle.net/pxFcw/

The option is to add a new class without removing .nav_btn, or if you prefer you could use the data object to store this info.

```
$('.nav_btn').on('click',function() {
         if(!$(this).hasClass("ishidden"))
         {
            $('nav').animate({marginLeft: '-245'}, 500);
             $(".nav_btn").addClass("ishidden");
         }
          else
          {
                $('nav').animate({marginLeft: '245'}, 500);
             $(".nav_btn").removeClass("ishidden");          
          }
        });
```

With the data object, it would be like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/dactivo/HjuFA/

```
  $('.nav_btn').on('click',function() {
         if(!$('.nav_btn').data("ishidden"))
         {
            $('nav').animate({marginLeft: '-245'}, 500);
             $('.nav_btn').data("ishidden",true);    
         }
          else
          {
                $('nav').animate({marginLeft: '245'}, 500);
                $('.nav_btn').data("ishidden",false);    
          }
        });
```

**OLDER ANSWER 2**

Ok, right now I know why this is not working, you are removing the class "nav_btn" and then assigning the class "nav_btn2" to an "object" that does not exist(because you have remove nav_btn).

You have to add class nav_btn2 and then remove.

**OLDER ANSWER 1: Only for Jquery versions < 1.7 as @Anthony Grist commented.**

You have to use live event, to associate the event for buttons that do not exist when you establish the event:
http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('.nav_btn').live("click", function(){
     ...
    });
  $('.nav_btn2').live("click", function(){
     ...
    });
```

Comment: `live()` is deprecated in 1.7, should be using `on()` (which they are) for jQuery 1.7+, or `delegate()` otherwise.

Comment: @Anthony Grist: Thx, it's true, I will put a note on the top of my answer, I leave it in case of user using an older version

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, sorry for the late reply. Fell asleep typing... Gonna try ur recommendation out & report back.

Comment: Ps. I'm using Jquery v>1.7, it's all good. Gonna try @netadictos recommendation with delegate(). Maybe it'll make a difference.

Comment: @Terry: look my new modificacion to my answer, it is logical I think.